# RMI client 'cannot cast' exception

Tags: java, registry, rmi, classcastexception, stub

I am trying to write a client programme in RMI that copy file from the server programme :

FileClientInt interface

```
public interface FileClientInt extends Remote {

    public boolean sendData(String fileName, byte[] data, int len) throws RemoteException;

    public String getName() throws RemoteException;

}
```

FileServerInt interface

```
public interface FileServerInt extends Remote {


public boolean login(FileClientInt c) throws RemoteException;
```

}

FileClient Class

```
public class FileClient extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FileClientInt {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String name;

public FileClient(String n) throws RemoteException {
    super();
    name = n;
}

public String getName() throws RemoteException {
    return name;
}

public boolean sendData(String filename, byte[] data, int len) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        File f = new File(filename);
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
        out.write(data, 0, len);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Done writing data...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

StartFileClient Class

```
public class StartFileClient {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileClient c = new FileClient("out.txt");
        FileServerInt server  = (FileServerInt) Naming.lookup("rmi://192.168.2.15");            
        server.login(c);
        System.out.println("Listening.....");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and it give me error :

```
Error sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub cannot be cast to myfileclient.FileServerInt
```

how can i resolve this error? can any body help in this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the object name on the end of your Registry lookup string. So you got the Registry itself, instead of the remote interface you were looking up.